# Send email to many recipients

Tags: python, email

I need to send an email to 100 recipients. When I send message to one recipient, it takes three seconds. And when I send it to three recipients at once, it also takes three seconds.

So I use multiple recipient to send the message faster.

```
def send(x, y, z):
    to = [x, y, z]
    subject="Multi Test"
    gmail_user = 'test@gmail.com'
    gmail_pwd = 'test'
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo
    smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    header = 'To:' + ", ".join(to) + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject: ' + subject + '\n'
    msg = header + '\n' + subject + '\n\n'
    smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
    smtpserver.close()
```

the email that i want to send message for is

```
1@yahoo.com, 2@yahoo.com, 3@yahoo.com....., 100@yahoo.com
```

so i want the script split into threes emails then send the message

or if you know another way to create script to send the message faster

Comment: check this: http://oao.no/wpe/2013/03/python-script-sends-bulk-email/

Comment: State your business...

Comment: Since you're apparently trying to figure out how to spam Yahoo accounts from Gmail, you should remember to always include `, abuse@yahoo.com, abuse@gmail.com` on the end of every `To:` line.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to

```
def send(to):
    // ..
    header = 'To:' + ", ".join(to)
```

Then call it as

```
send(["1@yahoo.com", "2@yahoo.com", "3@yahoo.com", ..., "100@yahoo.com"])
```

But think about the following:

- If you do this, every recipient will know that you send the email to *all* other 99 recipients.
- You should use [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email.message.html) to build an email. Don't just concat strings.

Comment: Can the script send to 100 email in one time ?

Comment: There is no reason why not. But you will have  to try if the SMP server accepts such a message.